# Sound glitches (repeats) momentarily

Tags: 12.04, sound, vlc, dvd

Since upgrading to 12.04 (64-bit), i've noticed an issue while watching DVDs in VLC - the sound will "glitch" - that is, it'll replay a tiny sample over and over for about a second or so, and then continue playing.

It's the same effect as if you're listening to something and your machine locks up hard, and it plays the same sound ad nauseum until you cut power. However, in my case, it clears after approximately a second.

During this time, the video continues to play uninterrupted. The sound resumes in time with the video (everything that would have been played during that second is lost - it doesn't replay it quickly or get behind).

Advice on debug steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see it outside of just VLC too - watching flash videos does it as well.

Comment: I've got the same problem as Matt and have improved the issue greatly (not solved) with updating ALSA from running through the following steps: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) In addition, I'm only having this issue on a system that is using a Realtek ALC887-VD card together with ATI 5450 card (HDMI). Are you running this hardware as well?